# bootstrap 4 column spacing not responding in laravel project

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a simple problem, I just started using bootstrap 4 for my laravel project and recently i have been trying to fix the columns, 3 columns per row. Cant seem to get the columns to respond to the page, i'm sure i have bootstrap 4 installed. What am i doing wrong?

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">    
    @foreach($products as $product)
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
           <h1>{{$product->title}}</h1>
           <p>{{$product->desc}}</p>    
       </div>   
    @endforeach
  </div>    
</div>   
@endsection
```

Comment: Are your getting 2 columns?

Comment: "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows." __ [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Switch the container and the row div's.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you can't believe i missed that @tahapaksu

Comment: You're welcome.